# Magento 2.2.4 - Checkout summary in custom phtml

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, magento2.2.4

I have a custom off-canvas sidebar (foundation 6) which I declared via a standard phtml template. It shows only in the checkout.

Now I would like to display the content of the checkout's sidebar (summary, cart_items etc.) inside of it.

I figure I need to initialize a component via knockout:

```
<div class="off-canvas position-right" id="offcanvas-sidebar" data-off-canvas>
    <button aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close="">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>

    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('summary') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->   

    <div class="opc-block-shipping-information">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shipping-information') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#offcanvas-sidebar": {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/core/app": {
               ... and here I am lost
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have no idea how to do the proper initialization so the templates summary and `shipping_information` are available.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you initialising a new UI component? If all you need to do is wrap the existing sidebar in your own markup and styling just overwrite `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html` into your theme and add the HTML you need.

If you need to do anything more advanced than this such as move the sidebar in the DOM you're limited to what scope of the checkout which is defined on the element `.checkout-container`.

If you look at how complex `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` is you'll see it isn't wise to make any large customisations to the M2 checkout. It's a complete minefield.

#### Default sidebar UI component config

This is the default sidebar UI component config, if you're creating your own you'll need to include this.

```
<item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/sidebar</item>
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">sidebar</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/sidebar</item>
    <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps</item>
    </item>
</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">summary</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary</item>
        </item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/totals</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary/totals</item>
                </item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                    <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart Subtotal</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping</item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                            <item name="notCalculatedMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not yet calculated</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- merge your components here -->
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail</item>
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before_details</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after_details</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- merge your components here -->
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item name="shipping-information" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress</item>
        </item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shipping-information</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="ship-to" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/list</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">ship-to</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: I need it in a sidebar (foundation 6). This sidebar cannot be triggered when added to the dom via knockout so I need to create an empty sidebar beforehand. All I want is that the mentioned knockout data will also be placed inside this sidebar.

I know that the magento checkout is a minefield (thank you varien, well done!).

My understanding of knockout is that I can place ko variables anywhere I like and don't have to worry about updating it's contents. 

So, all I need to know is what I initially asked for. I Know it is possible.

Comment: Why can it not be triggered? I feel it would be easier to fix that conflict than to create your own custom sidebar. I've included the default sidebar config to my answer, if you really want to create your own that is the config you need to pass through.

Comment: Why would I need to do this when it is already there? I am using the exact same ko variables as in sidebar.html. I just need a copy of the same in another template.

Comment: "My understanding of knockout is that I can place ko variables anywhere I like" - Incorrect, it has to be in the scope of the UI component, you aren't just working with KO you're working within the M2 checkout UI component which is incredibly complex.

Comment: You said you have created your own, if you are reusing the existing one there is no need to declare your own UI component. I'm confused now.

Comment: I don't even know what "declare your own UI component" means. All I need to know is to "mirror" the default sidebar's content into my own sidebar. Is such a simple thing really that complicated in m2?

Comment: It depends on many things, the main one being where in the DOM you need this sidebar. If it's within the scope of `.checkout-container.` you shouldn't need to do anything other than add your markup to `sidebar.html` as I put in my answer. If you are trying to add your sidebar outside of `.checkout-container.` then it's likely going to be a lot of work - more than I could add in a stack overflow answer. 

If I was doing this piece of work I would just update `sidebar.html` and fix any issues with the sidebar not opening, even a simple task such as moving a button in the checkout can take ages

Comment: shopware is looking better by the minute

Comment: I'm a big Shopware fanboy, so much simpler to work with. I feel like I spend so much time fighting Magento's code rather than working with it.